# Laravel 5.2 PHPUnit JSON Api request body not being set

Tags: php, json, laravel, phpunit, laravel-5

I am testing POSTing data to an API endpoint we've created using Laravel 5.2, but none of the parameters seem to be reaching the application in the test. The endpoint expects json and responds with json and uses a FormRequestValidator which has required rules for active and make parameters. The test fails with status code **422** and the examining the response body it states the active and make parameters are required even though they are being passed in the call so therefore for some reason when the request reaches the the Form Request Validator, the input is not there.

However, when I invoke the endpoint with json body including make and active from Postman or the UI app we've built it works fine, it is only failing in the PHPUnit tests therefore it must be something with PHPUnit or the test setup being incorrect. Here is the test:

```
public function testItStoresCars()
{
    // Arrange
    $user = User::first();

    //Act
    $this->json(Request::METHOD_POST, '/v1/cars', [
        'active' => true,
        'make' => 'Audi'
    ], 
    ['Authorization' => 'Bearer '.\JWT::fromUser($user)]));

    // Assert
    $this->assertResponseOk();
}
```

I know the Authorisation header is set correctly from other tests passing.

I've tried disabling middleware, using the `$this->post` helper method and manually setting the headers as well as using the `$this->call` method with setting the Headers and encoding the data using `json_encode` but I always get the same 422 response. I'm wondering has anyone encountered this issue or can see an error?

**Controller Code**

```
public function store(CreateCarRequest $request)
{
    $car = $this->carRepo->save($request->all());

    return response()->json(car);
}
```

**FormRequest**

```
class CreateCarRequest extends Request
{
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'active' => 'required|boolean',
        'make' => 'required',
    ];
}
}
```

Comment: $user = User::first();

    $this->actingAs($user); 

    $this->json('POST', '/vi1/cars', [
        'active' => true,
        'make' => 'Audi'
    ])->assertResponseOk()

try putting it this way, if it keeps failing, check the network tab in the Inspector and look for the request, what is the response or the preview?

Comment: as I mentioned in the question, it works fine in the browser from the UI app, and in Postman. Therefore the network tab and inspector don't shed any light on the issue. Its a problem with the PHPUnit test and the parameters either being lost or not being set causing the request to fail validation and 422 being returned (as expected when validation fails)

Comment: Please provide the controller action code & the validation rules for that request

Comment: Added the controller and form request, it's so basic. The code works fine when not being executed via PHPUnit tests, it's something to do with the TestCase I think

Answer (score 0):

422 is the error response for validation errors.. which means either your data is not posted or it doesn't pass server validation, try

```
$this->json(Request::METHOD_POST, '/v1/cars', [
        'active' => true,
        'make' => 'Audi'
    ], 
    ['Authorization' => 'Bearer '.\JWT::fromUser($user)]))->dump();
```

`dump()` should show you the errors

Comment: the errors are in the question, it seems like the data is not posted but I can't figure out why